# Netbeans - Removing the extra newlines in jsp/html

Tags: html, jsp, netbeans

Is there a method to remove the unnecessary newlines from my sources like jsp,html. The default formatter makes as below:

```
 <div class="container col-md-3">

        <div class="pull-right">

            <p>
                <button type="button" >Giriş</button>
            </p>


            <p>
                <button type="button" >Yeni Kayıt</button>
            </p>


         </div>

  </div>
```

and what I want is

```
<div class="container col-md-3">        
    <div class="pull-right">
        <p>
            <button type="button" >Giriş</button>
        </p>
        <p>
            <button type="button" >Yeni Kayıt</button>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Ctrl-H` to replace. Or go to `Edit -> Replace`. A menu will appear on the bottom of editor.
Select the `regular expression` checkbox.

Then put the following regex in `find what` field:

`^[\t ]{0,}\n`

And leave "replace with" blank.

The regex means "find a the begining of a line with any number of tabs or spaces followed by a newline.

Answer (score 0):

There is no shortcut or any other think for doing what you want